# Django- drf- social oauth2, convert_token, throws the error {"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Authentication process canceled"}

Tags: django-rest-framework, oauth, django-authentication

I am encountering an issue with the Django Rest Framework Social OAuth2 when attempting to obtain an access token using the Facebook login in my React frontend. Here are the details of the problem:

I can successfully obtain an access token from Facebook using the React frontend.

When I use the curl command with grant_type=password, I can obtain the token successfully.

curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&username=&password=" http://localhost:8000/auth/token/
However, when I use the curl command with grant_type=convert_token, I encounter the following error:

curl -X POST -d "grant_type=convert_token&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&backend=facebook&token=<facebook_token>" http://localhost:8000/auth/convert-token
Error: {"error":"access_denied","error_description":"Authentication process canceled"}

What could be causing the "Authentication process canceled" error when using grant_type=convert_token?

Any insights or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!